# Inheriting a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript

I have a JS definition like this in a .js file which is included in my .html file.

```
function chat() {
  this.sendNew() = function() { 
  [ .. ]
  }
}
```

Now I want to add another .js file which can extend this function with more methods, like this

```
function chat() { 
  this.anotherMethod = function() { 
  }
}
```

Is this possible? If yes, how? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add methods/attributes to the `.prototype` object:

```
chat.prototype.anotherMethod = function () {
    // ...
}
```

Just remember that `.prototype` is a property of functions, and then should be accessed by `chat`, and not by one of its instances.

You can read more about `.prototype` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that `chat()` was instantiated later in the code using `ch = new chat()`. So, finally I ended up added new method to `ch` itself. Thanks anyways!

Comment: You can also assign `anotherMethod` to the instance by doing `ch.anotherMethod = ...`, but then you'll only be extending the instance rather than the class itself.

Comment: You are right, but got insightful info about prototype today, thanks :)